# "Tapestry" constant (?) in tapestry5-high

Tags: javascript, java, tapestry

I'm would like to ask if anybody knows what is/does `"Tapestry.DEBUG_ENABLED = true;"`

Espceially I mean `Tapestry`. I belive that this is causing exception in my browser [image]

You can find direct link to line that points to class that is producing this piece of code [here](https://github.com/eliwan/tapestry5-high/blob/master/src/main/java/be/eliwan/tapestry5/high/services/HighchartsStack.java) (line 78)

I'm using Tapestry 5.4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there was no other way as edit and delete uncessary lines.

They were unfortunatley copied from old solution and that's why causing problems.

I've created a pull request.